# Why is the button not on the side for both phones?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I tried doing auto layout, making the button appear on the edges, but on the iphone 5 it's on the edge and on the iphone 6 it's in the middle region.

```
 next = UIButton()
    let me = "next.png"
    next.setImage(UIImage(named: me), forState: .Normal)
    next.frame = CGRectMake(250, 370, 40, 40)
    next.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    next.addTarget(self,action: "nexter:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(next)

    let horizontalConstraintnext = NSLayoutConstraint(item: next, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 285)
    view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraintnext)

    let verticalConstraintnext = NSLayoutConstraint(item: next, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 350)
    view.addConstraint(verticalConstraintnext)

    let widthConstraintnext = NSLayoutConstraint(item: next, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40)
    next.addConstraint(widthConstraintnext)

    let heightConstraintnext = NSLayoutConstraint(item: next, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 40)
    next.addConstraint(heightConstraintnext)
```

Comment: Because the devices have different widths.

Answer (score 0):

The computer is doing exactly what you told it to do. You are saying in your constraints "Put this button 285 points from the left edge". Well, where that appears to be in relation to the *whole* screen obviously depends on where the screen's *right* edge is!

So, if that isn't what you mean, don't say that. For example, if you want to fix it relative to the right edge, then fix it relative to the right edge, not the left edge.

Answer (score 0):

You have your button's leading set to a constant 285 points from the leading of the view controller's content view. The iPhone 5 has a narrower screen than the 6.

I wouldn't expect that to be at the edge of either the iPhone 5 or the iPhone 6. However, the 6 has a wider screen, so it's going to be closer to the center on the 6 than it will be on the 5. Why don't you try a much smaller constant value like 20 in your horizontal constraint?

Answer (score 0):

In the following lines:

```
let horizontalConstraintnext = NSLayoutConstraint(item: next, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 285)
view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraintnext)
```

You pin the left side of the button to the 285 from the left side of the view.  There is no reason the button would then follow the width of the screen because you are pinning it to always be 285 away from the left side.  What you need to do is pin the trailing space of the button to the superview by the amount of padding you want on the right side, say 10 in padding.

Try something like this:

```
let horizontalConstraintnext = NSLayoutConstraint(item: next, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
    view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraintnext)
```